# Can I delete community page from the "Build your own template"?

Tags: community

I started a new community from "Build your own" template.

The request is to delete some pages from this template. e.g.: Create Record.

Any suggestion to do so? thanks
[image: inline]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **cannot delete** default template pages but only the custom that you create. Refer to the below excerpt from the [help link](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_delete_page.htm&type=5):

> Keep in mind that you can’t delete:
>
> 1. The default pages and objects that come with the template
> 2. A page’s default page variation
> 3. A custom object page (detail, list, or related list) but you can delete the entire object

Comment: That's odd. Because I gonna to make a new community template but don't need some pages. Any solution to fix this? thanks!

Comment: It still doesn't matter if those pages are there or not. You can just ignore it as good as any standard feature that you don't want to utilize. But you definitely cannot delete it as mentioned.

Comment: Is it possible to exclude unwanted pages when I package them. I think we could do something on the metadata files. Will give it a try